# Uploading data on apache tomcat gives the error java.nio.Buffer.limit(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, wolfram-mathematica

We have built a webMathematica website using apache tomcat servlet. The webapp worked fine for some time, but since the last month we are getting errors while uploading files of size more than 8 kb. I am suspecting its a Java problem however any help will be appreciated.

The versions:
Apache Tomcat 8.0.9,
Java jdk1.7.0_71,
Windows Server 2008

## Here is the localhost log:

```
16-Jan-2015 13:43:43.506 SEVERE [ajp-nio-8009-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/webMathematica] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] with root cause
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProcessor.readSocket(AjpNioProcessor.java:179)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProcessor.read(AjpNioProcessor.java:159)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.readMessage(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:1059)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.receive(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:997)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.refillReadBuffer(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:1117)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:1720)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:328)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:887)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:94)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:593)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:619)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:638)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:961)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:942)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:349)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at com.wolfram.msp.MSPKernelRequest.processMultipartContent(MSPKernelRequest.java:523)
    at com.wolfram.msp.MSPKernelRequest.acquireKernel(MSPKernelRequest.java:168)
    at com.wolfram.msp.tags.EvaluateTag.doTag(EvaluateTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.Examples.Data.Upload_jsp._jspx_meth_msp_005fevaluate_005f0(Upload_jsp.java:164)
    at org.apache.jsp.Examples.Data.Upload_jsp._jspService(Upload_jsp.java:116)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:823)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try the Tomcat mailing list.

Comment: https://www.netroby.com/view.php?id=3585 <--- Maybe this will help.
Most servers have an config file where the max amount of a POST method can be adjusted.

Comment: Tried that already, the config files are at their default values (50 MB)

Comment: Tomcat 8.0.17 was released recently. 8.0.9 was the first "stable" release for 8. I would suggest updating to 8.0.17 and see if the issue still exists. As you can see, there have been many fixes:  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/changelog.html

Comment: We have updated to Tomcat 8.0.17, yet the same issue.